# Xamarin android build never completes using visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I created a new Xamarin android solution in VisualStudio 2015. I can build the project. but when I try to deploy to an running VS android emulator (5.1" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XXHDPI Phone) it never deploys. 
project properties:
Use latest Platform (Android 7.1)
Minimum android target 5.0

Comment: I turned off Hyper-v and used the AVDs. then the build deployed to the emulator successfully. What would be the problem with using a Visual Studio android emulator? The VS Emulator starts fine.

Comment: This started happening to me around 2 Xamarin updates ago. I've found I can click Build > Cancel, wait a few seconds, then deploy again and it works the second time. It will always fail the first time though.